# red × when deploy the contract on the online remix

Tags: solidity, contract, go-ethereum, remix

[image: the online remix log]

[image: the miner log]

As the above log , it prompts the contract was deployed successfully ,but why is there still the red ×？

http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=true&version=soljson-v0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.js

Comment: It likely ran out of gas

Comment: uh? how to modify the gas on the online remix-solidty? @Raghav Sood